# Regex in PHP: take all the words after the first one in string and truncate all of them to the first character

Tags: regex, string, preg-replace, preg-match, substr

I'm quite terrible at regexes.

I have a string that may have 1 or more words in it (generally 2 or 3), usually a person name, for example:

```
$str1 = 'John Smith';
$str2 = 'John Doe';
$str3 = 'David X. Cohen';
$str4 = 'Kim Jong Un';
$str5 = 'Bob';
```

I'd like to convert each as follows:

```
$str1 = 'John S.';
$str2 = 'John D.';
$str3 = 'David X. C.';
$str4 = 'Kim J. U.';
$str5 = 'Bob';
```

My guess is that I should first match the first word, like so:

```
preg_match( "^([\w\-]+)", $str1, $first_word )
```

then all the words after the first one... but how do I match those? should I use again preg_match and use offset = 1 in the arguments? but that offset is in characters or bytes right?

Anyway after I matched the words following the first, if the exist, should I do for each of them something like:

```
$second_word = substr( $following_word, 1 ) . '. ';
```

Or my approach is completely wrong?

Thanks

ps - it would be a boon if the regex could maintain the whole first two words when the string contain three or more words... (e.g. 'Kim Jong U.').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done in single `preg_replace` using a regex.

You can search using this regex:

```
^\w+(?:$| +)(*SKIP)(*F)|(\w)\w+
```

And replace by:

```
$1.
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL8lH5/1)

**Code:**

```
$name = preg_replace('/^\w+(?:$| +)(*SKIP)(*F)|(\w)\w+/', '$1.', $name);
```

**Explanation:**

- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in above regex.
- `^\w+(?:$| +)(*SKIP)(*F)` matches first word in a name and skips it (does nothing)
- `(\w)\w+` matches all other words and replaces it with first letter and a dot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a positive lookbehind assertion.

```
(?<=\h)([A-Z])\w+
```

OR

Use this regex if you want to turn `Bob F` to `Bob F.`

```
(?<=\h)([A-Z])\w*(?!\.)
```

Then replace the matched characters with `\1.`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mL8lH5/4)

Code would be like,

```
preg_replace('~(?<=\h)([A-Z])\w+~', '\1.', $string);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mL8lH5/3)

- `(?<=\h)([A-Z])` Captures all the uppercase letters which are preceeded by a horizontal space character.
- `\w+` matches one or more word characters.
- Replace the matched chars with the chars inside the group index 1 `\1` plus a dot will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with only look-ahead and word boundary check:

```
preg_replace('~(?!^)\b(\w)\w+~', '$1.', $string);
```

- `(\w)\w+` is a word in the name, with the first character captured
- `(?!^)\b` performs a word boundary check `\b`, and makes sure the match is not at the start of the string `(?!^)`.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uE4sH8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Simply start matching from the second character of the last (non-first) word of the string -- then replace that match with a dot (not capturing or referencing is needed).

Match a literal space, then `\w` to match a word character, then forget those characters with `\K`, then match zero or more word characters until the end of the string to ensure that all last names are truncated after their first letter and add a dot on the end.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PaK3f))

```
$strings = [
    'John Smith',
    'John Doe',
    'David X. Cohen',
    'Kim Jong Un',
    'Bob',
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('/ \w\K\w*$/', '.', $strings)
);
```